# Work with two tables twice

Tags: mysql

I have two tables like such:

Users (table 1)

```
Id  name  email  phone role etc
-------------------------------
65  yotav y@.com 888   crm  ...
20  tobi  t@.com 999.  User ...
```

Crm_lead (table 2)

```
Id  user_id  lead_id
--------------------
1.  65.      85
2.  65.      20
3.  65.      65
```

I need to make a query that would make the following table

```
Id name   email  phone role userid(from crm_lead)
-----------------------------------------------
65 yotav  y@.com 888   crm. Yotav
20 tobi.   .........        Yotav
```

In other words, I need to, according to the CRM lead, add the user's sale name to the user.

How would I do this?

Comment: I try join but it give me the user id i need the convert it to the name

Comment: There is likely a simple problem with your join.  If you post your syntax, someone will be able to tell you what needs to be corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this join

```
SELECT b.id, b.name, b.email, b.phone, b.role, a.name
FROM Users a
JOIN Crm_lead c ON a.id = c.user_id
RIGHT JOIN Users b ON c.lead_id = b.id;
```

Comment: its work good but its show only the user how have saleman i need all the users

Comment: @YotavMasa Try again. I have changed the join to a right join to show all users